# nvm - How does it pass custom flags to NPM

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, nvm

Whenever I run `npm install` I see that npm has been passed certain flags like `NVM_CD_FLAGS` how does nvm do this? does it actually have some other script in place of npm?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like npm is not getting replaced

```
> which npm
/Users/welldan97/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin/npm
> cat $(which npm)
#!/usr/bin/env node
;(function () { // wrapper in case we're in module_context mode
  // windows: running "npm blah" in this folder will invoke WSH, not node.
  /*global WScript*/
...
```

and the contents is the same as on npm github repo

looks like it sets it as environment variable

https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/nvm.sh#L226

```
> env | grep NVM
NVM_DIR=/Users/welldan97/.nvm
NVM_CD_FLAGS=-q
NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist
NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://iojs.org/dist
NVM_BIN=/Users/welldan97/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/bin
```

Then again, not sure where these flags go to, and if they affect npm